# Linking two excel spreadsheets Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one spreadsheet (A) acting as a register which gives me total attendance day by day, I use another spreadsheet that calculated monthly averages etc. I link Spreadsheet A to B so both spreadsheets have a daily total.

On Spreadsheet A I use =SUM in a specified range, currently I have made sure there is no data in specific range so all columns = 0 However on spreadsheet B it has two values '1' in cells that are linked to Spreadsheet A. I've checked spreadsheet A and there is no data.

Any idea whats going on and how to rectify it?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I am confused... You need to show a clear example of source and result.

Comment: Spreadsheet A: Cell A1 has calculated my total for Column A

Spreadsheet B: Takes the total of each column and then makes various calculations such as average.
I have linked Spreadsheet A Cell A1 with Spreadsheet B B1 but on spreadsheet B the value is 1, whereas the value in spreadsheet A Cell A1 is 0.

Comment: no improvement then, update the question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't recreate it because on a new spreadsheet the problem doesn't occur... 
I don't think there was any need to be rude.

Comment: I was not rude. I asked for a clear example  of source and result - which is what the FAQ suggests when you post questions.

Comment: " on spreadsheet B it has two values '1' in cells that are linked to Spreadsheet A. ".. try to re-establish the link. I mean either 'recreate' the formula or data link, and do a save as.. is there a difference?.